# My Microdata doesn't validate: "The itemprop attribute was specified, but the element is not a property of any item."

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I'm trying to validate a webpage with some Microdata in the [Schema.org](http://schema.org/) format, but I get a lot of errors of the type:

> The `itemprop` attribute was specified, but the element is not a property of any item.

This is the general structure of my markup:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ProductModel" itemprop="mainEntity">
    <meta itemprop="productID" content="XYZ0001" />
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Product XYZ" />

    <table>
        <tr itemscope itemprop="additionalProperty" itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
            <th><span itemprop="name">Foo</span></th>
            <td><span itemprop="value">1197</span></td>                                 
        </tr>
        <tr itemscope itemprop="additionalProperty" itemtype="http://schema.org/PropertyValue">
            <th><span itemprop="name">Bar</span></th>
            <td><span itemprop="value">Blah blah</span></td>                                    
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I'm using `ProductModel` and `additionalProperty` since the page entity doesn't have a more suitable predefined type (yet). Am I making any obvious mistakes in the markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify `itemprop` on an element, there must be a parent element with `itemscope`.

Unless you have such a parent element not shown in the snippet, this is likely the line that gives the error:

> ```html
> <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ProductModel" itemprop="mainEntity">
> ```

I assume you want to convey that this `ProductModel` is the main entity of the web page, so you could specify:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ProductModel" itemprop="mainEntity">
    <!-- … -->
  </div>
</div>
```

(Or one of the more specific sub-types, if applicable, e.g., [`ItemPage`](http://schema.org/ItemPage).)